# option list is not loading when i select from another list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have two SELECT menus , The first is is the category i am suppose to choose from and the other is the optgroup of the category i choose from the other menu , When i choose from the first i expect the second to load the optgroup related to the category i choose but it does not

HTML & PHP : (SELECT options is loaded from database)

```
<select name="workout" id="exc">
<optgroup label="Legs">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT excercise FROM legs";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['excercise']."'>".$row['excercise']."</option>";
    }
?>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Biceps">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT excercise FROM biceps";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row['excercise']."'>".$row['excercise']."</option>";
    }
?>
</optgroup>

</select>
```

Javascript (JQUERY)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#filter").on("change", function() {
    $exc = $("#exc");
    $exc.find("optgroup").hide().children().hide();
    $exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "']").show().children().show();
    $exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "'] option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
  });
});
```

Anyone can tell me why it is not working as expected ??
Example of what i need to achieve is here :

[JSFIFDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yt0dekfy/)

thanks for help :)

[image: that is what i have on my console]

Comment: in jsfiddler it works. What exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: You have a separate table for each muscle group? Is that smart?

Comment: The normal mechanism used in these situations is to load the first dropdown from the PHP like you have, but to load the second you run an ajax call, pass it the value of dropdown 1 and then load the second dropdown from the results of the ajax call.

Comment: @RiggsFolly there is no `normal mechanism`. If data collection is small nothing wrong with approach being used. AJAX is not necessary all the time

Comment: @OlegDubas it is  not working on my computer ! i do not know why !

Comment: What browser do you use? OS? Try Ctrl+F5 it

Comment: Are errors thrown? If it works in a demo but not on your page something is different

Comment: Have you included the JQuery library in the HTML for this page?

Comment: This can be done without AJAX if he puts a jsonified object that contains the option values and builds the selects out based on that object. That's how I've done it before anyway.

Comment: jquery library in included and the script is on another seperate js file and it is included in head tag of the html page

Comment: I am using windows and chrome browser

Comment: You haven't mentioned errors. Are errors thrown is important to know. Also have you checked files are actually loading in your console?

Comment: in console i have this : 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function load_selection.js:2(anonymous function) and it is pointing to this line : 
$("#filter").on("change", function() {

Comment: please help guys because i am stuck !

Comment: @wfareed your fiddle works fine. Do you load your script after JQuery?

Comment: Yes i did , does it have to do anything with fetching data from mysql database ? which ii should do first ! load the js script then running the php script to get data from DB or load the js after getting all data from mysql ?

Comment: @wfareed No, it doesn't. You have an error in your JS, which has nothing to do with your PHP script. Which version of JQuery are you using? Do you have any other JS scripts included in your project?

Comment: v1.6.2 but i do not think it is a version related issue because other applications using the same version and working just fine

Comment: @wfareed well, you're using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which was added in 1.7 version. Try using a different version of JQuery (> 1.7).

Comment: :) perfect , working just fine now after downloading latest version , Thanks @Vucko

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69555/discussion-between-wfareed-and-vucko).

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, you're using `JQuery` version **1.6.2**, and in you script you have [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which was added in `JQuery` **1.7.** version. Update your version of `JQuery` (**>1.7**) and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Case A:
Use "bind" instead of "on" in case you use jQuery 1.6.4 or lower.
http://jsfiddle.net/yt0dekfy/6/

```
$("#filter").bind("change",function() {
    $exc = $("#exc");
    $exc.find("optgroup").hide().children().hide();
    $exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "']").show().children().show();
    $exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "'] option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
});
```

Case B:
Simply use "change" instead of "on".
http://jsfiddle.net/yt0dekfy/7/

```
$("#filter").change(function() {
    $exc = $("#exc");
    $exc.find("optgroup").hide().children().hide();
    $exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "']").show().children().show();
    $exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "'] option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
});
```

Case C:
Update to a higher version of jQuery (>1.7) if you want to use the "on" selector
http://jsfiddle.net/yt0dekfy/8/

```
$("#filter").on("change",function() {
    $exc = $("#exc");
    $exc.find("optgroup").hide().children().hide();
    $exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "']").show().children().show();
    $exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "'] option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#filter").on("change excReady", function() {
$exc = $("#exc");
$exc.find("optgroup").hide().children().hide();
$exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "']").show().children().show();
$exc.find("optgroup[label='" + this.value + "'] option").eq(0).prop("selected", true);
});
$("#exc").ready(function(){
    $("#filter").trigger("excReady");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yt0dekfy/9/)